# Maven compiler plugin always detecting a set of sources as "stale"

Tags: java, maven, build

FIXED: this is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209) in maven-compiler-plugin 3.1

I am converting an ant-based build of a 1000+ java-sources project to maven. So far so good, but every time launch `mvn compile` it recompiles everything (instead of reusing old classes)

Using `mvn -X compile` reports that

```
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: /project_path/src/main/java/package_path/AFile1.java
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: /project_path/src/main/java/package_path/AFile2.java
...
```

(**only for files in a certain package**, which is possibly unreferenced from the rest of the code; not my sources, I am just trying to mavenize the build)

Compilation does not fail, and classes with updated timestamps are being generated at

```
/project_path/target/classes/package_path/AFile1.class
/project_path/target/classes/package_path/AFile2.class
...
```

However, when looking at timestamps, the java files have not changed since yesterday, and the class files are current. Why are these sources determined to be stale? How can I debug this issue?.

It is a drag to have to recompile 1k+ files even when no changes have occurred...

---

Sample output:

```
$ mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for net.sourceforge:jffmpeg:jar:1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Deleting /project_path/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ my-project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /project_path/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1162 source files to project_path/target/classes
....
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.215s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 30 12:42:25 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/429M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------



$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for net.sourceforge:jffmpeg:jar:1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ my-project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /project_path/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1162 source files to /project_path/target/classes
... 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.140s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 30 12:42:44 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/379M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Providing you don't do a `mvn clean compile` Maven will only compile the source files that have changed; see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772747/how-does-maven-compile-only-the-modified-java-files

Comment: That is what I thought. However, it is not what I get...

Comment: @tucuxi: Add an answer :)

Comment: pom.xml - look in the maven-compiler- plugin section

Comment: This is the good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963012/maven-compiler-recompile-all-files-instead-modified

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a known problem in maven-compiler-plugin 3.1. It is being tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209 (the `useIncrementalCompilation` flag is broken).

The problem is unrelated to another 3.1 bug, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-205 (where files that do not produce .class outputs are always flagged as 'stale').

After testing further, going back to 3.0 did not actually fix the problem (it only works until the next `mvn clean compile`. However, as Michael Lemke suggests in comments, marking `useIncrementalCompilation` to `false` is a workable substitute; now, only the offending package gets recompiled each time (instead of the whole code-base).

Comment: I am seeing the same kind of problem.  Using 3.0 doesn't help in my case, though. I just keep using 3.1 and set `useIncrementalCompilation` to false.  Fixes it for me.

I am actually modifying a single Java file with the replacer plugin which causes this unfortunate behavior.

Comment: If you rewrite your comment as an answer, I will accept it as the correct answer. Backing up to 3.0 only worked until the next full mvn clean compile...

Comment: Hi, how exactly do we go in and change "useIncrementalCompilation" to false?  What file does that live in?  Thanks!

Comment: @mattman88 This can be set in the pom.xml file:                
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Comment: Actually according to the last comment at both those issues, it is not broken, but people perceive wrong on what that setting is supposed to do. Actually, you should use true and avoid using false there

Answer (score 46):

Maven may show a message like:

> [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!

Because you have an empty java file (or all commented out) in the project that never compiles into a class file.

You can identify the reason why maven rebuilds by running maven with -X. Look near the above message.

Comment: I was experiencing same issue with v3.7.0.  This is the best answer.  If you run `mvn -X` you will see: `[DEBUG] useIncrementalCompilation enabled` followed by ... `[DEBUG] Stale source detected: ${filePath}` and it was 2x empty source files in my project.  BRILLIANT!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Removing files that have been commented for more than two years (no idea why they were still there in the first place), I managed reduce compilation time with more than 50%.

Comment: The -X find the issue... I added a package-info.java with only comments to describe the package and it shows as stale. Too bad!

Comment: it is treating package-info.java as empty (which only contains javadoc).

Comment: In my case, the `-X` option help me understand that it is a generated file by antlr3, need to understand why it gets regenerated every time.

Answer (score 19):

Faced the same problem. Maven `mvn compile` with `-X` option showed that the problem is caused by `package-info.java` file.

> [DEBUG] Stale source detected: .../package-info.java

The problem is that there is no **.class** file generated for `package-info.java`.

The solution was found in this PR: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/5644/files
referencing [MCOMPILER-205](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-205)

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>-Xpkginfo:always</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

which means:

> Always generate package-info.class for every package-info.java file.

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.earcam.wrapped/jdk.compiler/1.8.132/com/sun/tools/javac/main/Option.PkgInfo.html#ALWAYS `This option may be useful in conjunction with build systems (such as Ant) that expect javac to generate at least one .class file for every .java file.`

Comment: Note that the `package-info.java` file **must not be empty** to result into a `package-info.class` file

Answer (score 9):

My situation was slightly different, so I'm just adding this in case someone else has the same issue. My project has no generated classes and no `package-info.java`; only `.java` files in `src/main/java`.

**tl;dr**

Update to `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.1 or use `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.0 and do not set `<overwrite>true</overwrite>` in `maven-resources-plugin`.

---

**Long version**

With zero src tree changes, Maven was always showing output like:

```
$ mvn -o compile

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 134 source files to /home/me/my/project/target/classes
```

I thought it was the configuration of the `maven-resources-plugin` in a parent POM my project is using.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Removing this plugin from the parent POM, or redefining in my project with `<overwrite>false</overwrite>` fixed the incremental build problem.

I wondered why I had to do two builds after setting `<overwrite>false</overwrite>` for Maven to do incremental builds again, so investigated further. That is simply because the first compile generates a file (called `inputFiles.lst`) that is used to determine the files that have changed, so on the next compile it can use that file to detect changes. This is confirmed by [a comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-187?focusedCommentId=14428981&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14428981) on MCOMPILER-187.

I realised I was using `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.0 and could just upgrade to

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

which also fixed the problem. 3.1 uses [`maven-shared-incremental`](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-incremental/) 1.1 (instead of 1.0 which `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.0 uses. Note that [MCOMPILER-187](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-187) and [MSHARED-264](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-264) are the 2 bugs covering the change.

So back with maven-compiler-plugin 3.0, I observed that the `target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst` was not being generated with `<overwrite>true</overwrite>` set. So this *could* be a reason why a project fails to have incremental builds when using maven-compiler-plugin 3.0.

Clearly, overwriting the resources every compile is not usually desired, but the main problem here is that `inputFiles.lst` is never generated, so Maven will never be able to make an incremental build. So check for the existence of `inputFiles.lst` as maybe another plugin has somehow caused it to not be generated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why, but the solution from tucuxi's answer doesn't work in my case. In my project there are thousands of files generated by special tool and its recompilation may waste really a lot of time.

I've tried the following plugin configuration (with java level 1.5):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

On a second run, there are no stale files was detected but the plugin recompiled all the project again. It seems that incremental compilation actually disabled by default, and still not working even if useIncrementalCompilation=true specified.

After some googling, I've simply changed useIncrementalCompilation parameter value from "true" to "yes" and this do the trick for me.

@see also [stackoverflow.com/a/19653164/1848640](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653164/1848640)

Comment: "yes" here is the same as "false", as in: not "true"

Comment: He meant use <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
In the question you linked, any thing not "true" is "false", that's why "yes" gave you the "false" effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure there's been no change, you can pass in `-Dmaven.main.skip`. I have a project where I do this after running Proguard, since it's the only way to reuse the Proguarded jar for tests. (NB: I run the same unit tests before Proguard as after, to make sure Proguard hasn't broken anything. To bring this as close to the standard Maven workflow as possible, I do the pre-Proguard run in Surefire and the post-Proguard run in Failsafe.)

Comment: Thank you for an updated answer - Maven 3.5 2018/08/20

Answer (score 2):

This is a very edge case I had and was extremely hard to figure out.

In my project all test files in a certain package were recompiled every time although there were no changes.

Turns out that one of the folders was named `com.example` instead of just `com` with a subdir `example`. The IDE does not show this as it combines it to `com.example` so it was not obvious.

I had to debug the maven compiler plugin to find this out. The generated test classes were in a correct directory structure but the compiler plugin was looking for the class files in a `com.example` directory, which did not exist. And so all test files were marked as stale.

Solution was to rename the directory from `com.example` to `com` and create a new subdir `example` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Mismatch of classname and filename also produce this error.

Answer (score 0):

Another way this can happen is if your source file location and package name are mismatched.

e.g. if you have a source file in `src/main/java/com/example/MyClass.java` but the class is declared in a mismatched `com.example.util` package:

```
package com.example.util;

class MyClass { ... }
```

The compiled class file will end up in `target/classes/com/example/util/MyClass.class` and this will confuse the 'stale file' check.

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back maven compiler plugin to version 2.3.2 and it compiles only modified classes with java 8 without problems.