# Maven does not generate test classes from command line

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unit-testing, maven, junit4

When built from eclipse the test classes are generated under target/test-classes however this is empty (only the test resources are copies but no test classes ) when I run

```
mvn clean install
```

I see the following messages

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile)
@ core --- [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform
encoding US-ASCII, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling
46 source files to
/Users/root/Perforce/Server/DL/Server/dev/core/target/test-classes
[INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @
core ---
```

Wondering where did those classes go. When I ran

```
mvn -X install
```

I saw

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile)
@ core --- [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform
encoding US-ASCII, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling
46 source files to
/Users/root/Perforce/Server/DL/Server/dev/core/target/test-classes
[INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @
core ---

[DEBUG] Output directory:
/Users/root/Perforce/Server/DL/Server/dev/core/target/test-classess
[DEBUG] CompilerReuseStrategy: reuseCreated [DEBUG]
useIncrementalCompilation enabled [DEBUG] Stale source detected:
/Users/root/Perforce/Server/DL/Server/dev/core/src/test/java/test/datastore/FileTest.java
```

And all other files.

Please suggest any way to debug further why the compiled test classes are not present so that the tests can be run in the next phase.

Note that this is a sub project under a parent project and all other subproject's tests classes are compiled and run but not this one. Strange the parent POM has all the settings so not sure whats special about this

Comment: did you refresh your target folder after doing the build and have you enabled tests to be run when you do the mvn clean install

Comment: @vikeng21 I did not get you what do you mean by "refresh", I checked using "ls target/test-classes"

Comment: are you running the command in a unix/linux box and facing this issue or in windows. again have you enabled tests to be run

Comment: @vikeng21 Its a Mac so unix basically . Yes all the files ends with *Test and methods are annotated with @ Test. Runs just fine from Eclipse.

Comment: Show your full pom file and an example test class and where you have stored the test java file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven compiler plugin always detecting a set of sources as "stale"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944108/maven-compiler-plugin-always-detecting-a-set-of-sources-as-stale)

Comment: As you can see in the debug output it says "Stale source detected".  It is a known bug: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-209.

Comment: @maba I have tried setting useIncrementalCompilation to false but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem finally . The following file had a pattern mentioned which was ignoring the test cases not matching the pattern

```
src/test/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
```

I changed the pattern from

```
test.MyAnnotation
```

to

```
#test.MyAnnotation
```

and it worked ! Any guesses what was the problem and is it for selectively running tests ?