# Maven/Eclipse Attempts to Compile Tests with Main Code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am running eclipse oxygen (release 4.7.3a) with maven plugin m2e (1.8.3.20180227) and java 8 (jdk1.8.0_172)

**Updated eclipse** to Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), m2e 1.11.0.20190220-2119, java version unchanged. 
Same behavior persists.

I have a project with a module. 
The module has `/src/main/java` and `src/test/java`
The `junit` dependency is test scope.

When I run maven install I get errors during compile

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project something: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>
> [ERROR] /C:/Users/me/git/base/module/src/test/java/com/company/redacted/db/IsAdminQueryTest.java:[3,24] package org.junit does not exist

If I change the scope of `junit` to default it compiles and runs fine.

A perhaps related symptom If I run `Maven -> Update Project`, I get an error:

> Cannot nest 'module/src/main/resources' inside 'module/src/'. 
>   To enable nesting exclude 'main/' from 'module/src/'

However `module/src` is not a java source folder.

from the maven log during the compile stage when running with `-e -X`.

Note the **test** in the path

> [DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\me\git\base\module\src\main\java\com\company\redacted\db\IsAdminQuery.java
>
> [DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\ms\git\base\module\src\test\java\com\company\redacted\db\IsAdminQueryTest.java

Where should I look for the bad config?

**Update after upgrade**
I had changed the scope of junit and mockito to global to work around this problem. When I changed them back to scope: test the test case started having dependency issues/failure to compile. Clearly eclipse/maven doesn't know my test classes are test classes.

I have installed maven directly on my pc. Running mvn install from the command line has the same issues as running in eclipse.

Comment: Which version of java are you using ?

Comment: @Sambit do you want the java version for completeness, or is there a known issue?

Comment: You may have to update the m2e plugin.

Comment: move IsAdminQueryTest.java from src/main/... to src/test/ because the junit scope is test

Comment: @imperezivan That was a typo in the log file line. I went back an double checked. the test code is in fact in src/test/java. I have corrected the question.

Comment: looks like a maven plugin bug,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944108/maven-compiler-plugin-always-detecting-a-set-of-sources-as-stale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was something of an idiot. I am not sure how it happened (copy paste error perhaps)
but I had set the source directory in the build section of my pom.xml. Removing that solved all my problems.

Thanks to all who made suggestions especially [@Sambit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3127812/sambit).

```
  <build>
    **<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>**
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps in case of maven project.

- In a maven based project, before configuring the project, go to command prompt and run either `mvn clean install` or `mven clean package`.
- In case of Eclipse,I will suggest to use latest version of Eclipse. For existing maven project, use as Import Maven project in Eclipse. You have to go to File Menu > Import > Existing Maven project.
- Project in eclipse may take sometime depending upon the number of dependencies. After sometime, you have to click ALT+F5 by selecting the project.

Comment: I updated eclipse to Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0). No change in behavior

Comment: What is yor java version ?

Comment: java version is jdk1.8.0_172

Comment: Can you remove the line <scope>test</scope> for Junit and check ?

Comment: changing the scope of the junit dependancies to default allows the code to compile. the test code even gets included in my final jar. (not what I wanted)

Comment: If you have maven structure, the test classes will never go into the actual jar file. There will be separate jar file test classes.